Planting Sunflowers
I am new to this gardening stuff! I just bought 3 different kinds of sunflower seeds to plant along my fence line. My question is, can I mix the seeds up and plant them or do I plant the same kinds together?

You can plant the same kinds together - however if you want to collect seeds the new seeds you get will likely be hybrids.   If the Sunflowers grow to different heights, you may want to take the positioning of the various seeds into account.

The seed collecting aspect is no different "grouped" or "mixed" unless the "Grouped" case involves something like 1/4-1/2 mile (0.5-1 km) separation from other sunflowers... The average home gardener is unlikely to get "pure" seed even if they only grow one, unless the neighbors for quite some distance don't plant any of the same type of plant.
